# How to submit a form through JS if it has an input element named 'submit'?

Tags: javascript, forms, input, form-submit

Behold the following HTML form:

```html
<form id='bla'>
<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
<button onclick='document.getElementById("bla").submit()'> OK </button>
```

Clicking the button does *not* submit the form, because form.submit is now the input element named 'submit', rather than the form's submit function.

If the input element in the above example is named otherwise (e.g. `name='foobar'`) it works just fine.

I'm dealing with a context where I *need* to send along a value called 'submit' when submitting a form. How do I submit this form from JavaScript?